# Перекантоваться — происхождение слова

Tags: этимология, жаргон

"Перекантоваться" говорят о временном, как правило, вынужденном пребывании где-то. "Мне бы у вас перекантоваться недельку".
"Кантовать" груз — значит переворачивать его. А как это слово относится к временному пребыванию где-то?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Кантовка" груза - весьма нерациональный способ перемещения, и в плане трудозатрат, и по части сохранности содержимого. Вынужденно применяется в случаях особой необходимости.
Эта нерациональность, вынужденность, "некачественность" и послужила, видимо, причиной перенесения термина на существование в условиях дефицита комфорта. 
Я только немного поправлю. "Перекантоваться" - это не обязательно "где-то". Это скорее "как-то": без денег, без продуктов, одежды и проч. В условиях какого-то частичного дефицита. Если же "где-то", то это в плохой гостинице, например. Вряд ли в президентском номере приходится "перекантовываться".

Answer (score 1):

КАНТ-край,коомка,грань.Кантовать-переворачивать или перемещать с одного края на другой,окантовывать-обработать край,кромку,сторону,перекантовывать-перемещать,переворачивать с одного края на другой.ПЕРЕКАНТОВАТЬСЯ-переместиться,переернутся,с одного места на другое(с одного бока на другой лёжа в постели).